# Fragment ошибка

Tags: android, android-fragment

При попытке вставить фрагмент в `FrameLayout` (который находится в диалогом фрагменте), выскакивает ошибка. Вот код основного фрагмента:

```
public class AddWord_Fragment extends DialogFragment {
    MainActivity mainActivity;
    private static int form = 0;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setStyle(STYLE_NO_TITLE, 0);
    }

    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.words_add, null);
        mainActivity = (MainActivity) getActivity();

        Spinner spinner = (Spinner) v.findViewById(R.id.spinner_forms);
        ArrayAdapter<?> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(mainActivity, R.array.forms, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
        spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View itemSelected, int selectedItemPosition, long selectedId) {
                FragmentTransaction fTransaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                switch (selectedItemPosition) {
                    case 0:
                        fTransaction.add(R.id.frameLayout1_wordsAdd, new WordsAddForm1_Fragment());    
                        break;
                    case 1:
                        fTransaction.add(R.id.frameLayout1_wordsAdd, new WordsAddForm2_Fragment());
                        break;
                }
                fTransaction.commit();
                Log.i("APP", "6");
            }

            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
            }
        });

        Log.i("APP", "7");
        return v;
    }
}
```

Из лога видно, что 6 выводится в лог, а 7 — уже нет.

Вот .xml файл фрагмента:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="45dp"
    android:layout_margin="3dp"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spinner_forms"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="45dp" />
</LinearLayout>

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/frameLayout1_wordsAdd"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="3dp" >
</FrameLayout>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnOK_wordsadd"
    android:layout_width="300dp"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:layout_margin="3dp"
    android:background="@drawable/button1"
    android:text="Готово" />
```

А вот Java и .xml файл фрагмента, который я пытаюсь добавить:

```
public class WordsAddForm1_Fragment extends Fragment {
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.word_add_form1, null);
        return v;
    }
}
```

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv1_wordAddForm1"
        android:layout_width="80sp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Слово"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:textSize="18sp" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/et1_wordAddForm1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1" >
    </EditText>
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv2_wordAddForm1"
        android:layout_width="80sp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Перевод"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:textSize="18sp" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/et2_wordAddForm1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1" >
    </EditText>
</LinearLayout>
```

Ошибки из logcat`a:

```
10-14 15:14:24.473: ERROR/FragmentManager(15743): No view found for id 0x7f0a001b (com.example.dictionarydemo_2:id/frameLayout1_wordsAdd) for fragment WordsAddForm1_Fragment{42044978 #2 id=0x7f0a001b}
10-14 15:14:24.474: ERROR/FragmentManager(15743): Activity state:
10-14 15:14:24.479: ERROR/FragmentManager(15743):   Local Activity 41fd8bf0 State:
10-14 15:14:24.479: ERROR/FragmentManager(15743):     mResumed=true mStopped=false mFinished=false
10-14 15:14:24.479: ERROR/FragmentManager(15743):     mLoadersStarted=true
10-14 15:14:24.479: ERROR/FragmentManager(15743):     mChangingConfigurations=false
10-14 15:14:24.479: ERROR/FragmentManager(15743):     mCurrentConfig={1.0 255mcc1mnc ru_RU ldltr sw320dp w320dp h544dp 240dpi nrml long port finger -keyb/v/h -nav/h skin=/system/framework/framework-res.apk s.8}
10-14 15:14:24.479: ERROR/FragmentManager(15743):   Active Fragments in 41fd8ce8:
10-14 15:14:24.479: ERROR/FragmentManager(15743):     #0: Tabs_Fragment_1{41fd9a20 #0 id=0x7f0a0001}
10-14 15:14:24.479: ERROR/FragmentManager(15743):       mFragmentId=#7f0a0001 mContainerId=#7f0a0001 mTag=null
10-14 15:14:24.479: ERROR/FragmentManager(15743):       mState=5 mIndex=0 mWho=android:fragment:0 mBackStackNesting=0
10-14 15:14:24.479: ERROR/FragmentManager(15743):       mAdded=true mRemoving=false mResumed=true mFromLayout=false mInLayout=false
10-14 15:14:24.479: ERROR/FragmentManager(15743):       mHidden=false mDetached=false mMenuVisible=true mHasMenu=false
10-14 15:14:24.480: ERROR/FragmentManager(15743):       mRetainInstance=false mRetaining=false mUserVisibleHint=true
10-14 15:14:24.480: ERROR/FragmentManager(15743):       mFragmentManager=FragmentManager{41fd8ce8 in MainActivity{41fd8bf0}}
10-14 15:14:24.480: ERROR/FragmentManager(15743):       mActivity=com.example.dictionarydemo_2.MainActivity@41fd8bf0
10-14 15:14:24.480: ERROR/FragmentManager(15743):       mContainer=android.widget.FrameLayout{41fdb958 V.E..... ........ 0,0-480,60 #7f0a0001 app:id/tabs_frame}
10-14 15:14:24.480: ERROR/FragmentManager(15743):       mView=
10-14 15:14:24.481: ERROR/FragmentManager(15743): android.widget.LinearLayout{41fde340 V.E..... ........ 0,0-480,60 #7f0a000a app:id/ll_actionbar}
10-14 15:14:24.481: ERROR/FragmentManager(15743):     #1: AddWord_Fragment{42000020 #1 NewDictionaryInput}
10-14 15:14:24.481: ERROR/FragmentManager(15743):       mFragmentId=#0 mContainerId=#0 mTag=NewDictionaryInput
10-14 15:14:24.482: ERROR/FragmentManager(15743):       mState=5 mIndex=1 mWho=android:fragment:1 mBackStackNesting=0
10-14 15:14:24.482: ERROR/FragmentManager(15743):       mAdded=true mRemoving=false mResumed=true mFromLayout=false mInLayout=false
10-14 15:14:24.482: ERROR/FragmentManager(15743):       mHidden=false mDetached=false mMenuVisible=true mHasMenu=false
10-14 15:14:24.482: ERROR/FragmentManager(15743):       mRetainInstance=false mRetaining=false mUserVisibleHint=true
10-14 15:14:24.482: ERROR/FragmentManager(15743):       mFragmentManager=FragmentManager{41fd8ce8 in MainActivity{41fd8bf0}}
10-14 15:14:24.482: ERROR/FragmentManager(15743):       mActivity=com.example.dictionarydemo_2.MainActivity@41fd8bf0
10-14 15:14:24.482: ERROR/FragmentManager(15743):       mView=android.widget.LinearLayout{42000860 V.E..... ......I. 0,0-442,148}
10-14 15:14:24.482: ERROR/FragmentManager(15743):       DialogFragment:
10-14 15:14:24.482: ERROR/FragmentManager(15743):         mStyle=1 mTheme=0x0
10-14 15:14:24.482: ERROR/FragmentManager(15743):         mCancelable=true mShowsDialog=true mBackStackId=-1
10-14 15:14:24.482: ERROR/FragmentManager(15743):         mDialog=android.app.Dialog@420002b8
10-14 15:14:24.483: ERROR/FragmentManager(15743):         mViewDestroyed=false mDismissed=false mShownByMe=true
10-14 15:14:24.483: ERROR/FragmentManager(15743):     #2: WordsAddForm1_Fragment{42044978 #2 id=0x7f0a001b}
10-14 15:14:24.483: ERROR/FragmentManager(15743):       mFragmentId=#7f0a001b
10-14 15:14:24.484: ERROR/FragmentManager(15743):  mContainerId=#7f0a001b mTag=null
10-14 15:14:24.484: ERROR/FragmentManager(15743):       mState=0 mIndex=2 mWho=android:fragment:2 mBackStackNesting=0
10-14 15:14:24.484: ERROR/FragmentManager(15743):       mAdded=true mRemoving=false mResumed=false mFromLayout=false mInLayout=false
10-14 15:14:24.484: ERROR/FragmentManager(15743):       mHidden=false mDetached=false mMenuVisible=true mHasMenu=false
10-14 15:14:24.484: ERROR/FragmentManager(15743):       mRetainInstance=false mRetaining=false mUserVisibleHint=true
10-14 15:14:24.484: ERROR/FragmentManager(15743):       mFragmentManager=FragmentManager{41fd8ce8 in MainActivity{41fd8bf0}}
10-14 15:14:24.484: ERROR/FragmentManager(15743):       mActivity=com.example.dictionarydemo_2.MainActivity@41fd8bf0
10-14 15:14:24.484: ERROR/FragmentManager(15743):   Added Fragments:
10-14 15:14:24.484: ERROR/FragmentManager(15743):     #0: Tabs_Fragment_1{41fd9a20 #0 id=0x7f0a0001}
10-14 15:14:24.484: ERROR/FragmentManager(15743):     #1: AddWord_Fragment{42000020 #1 NewDictionaryInput}
10-14 15:14:24.484: ERROR/FragmentManager(15743):     #2: WordsAddForm1_Fragment{42044978 #2 id=0x7f0a001b}
10-14 15:14:24.485: ERROR/FragmentManager(15743):   FragmentManager misc state:
10-14 15:14:24.485: ERROR/FragmentManager(15743):     mActivity=com.example.dictionarydemo_2.MainActivity@41fd8bf0
10-14 15:14:24.485: ERROR/FragmentManager(15743):     mContainer=android.app.Activity$1@41fd8d60
10-14 15:14:24.485: ERROR/FragmentManager(15743):     mCurState=5 mStateSaved=false mDestroyed=false
10-14 15:14:24.485: ERROR/FragmentManager(15743):   ViewRoot:
10-14 15:14:24.485: ERROR/FragmentManager(15743):     mAdded=true mRemoved=false
10-14 15:14:24.485: ERROR/FragmentManager(15743):     mConsumeBatchedInputScheduled=false
10-14 15:14:24.488: ERROR/FragmentManager(15743):     mPendingInputEventCount=0
10-14 15:14:24.488: ERROR/FragmentManager(15743):     mProcessInputEventsScheduled=false
10-14 15:14:24.488: ERROR/FragmentManager(15743):     mTraversalScheduled=false
10-14 15:14:24.497: ERROR/FragmentManager(15743):     android.view.ViewRootImpl$NativePreImeInputStage: mQueueLength=0
10-14 15:14:24.497: ERROR/FragmentManager(15743):     android.view.ViewRootImpl$ImeInputStage: mQueueLength=0
10-14 15:14:24.497: ERROR/FragmentManager(15743):     android.view.ViewRootImpl$NativePostImeInputStage: mQueueLength=0
10-14 15:14:24.497: ERROR/FragmentManager(15743):   Choreographer:
10-14 15:14:24.497: ERROR/FragmentManager(15743):     mFrameScheduled=false
10-14 15:14:24.497: ERROR/FragmentManager(15743):     mLastFrameTime=851461765 (51 ms ago)
10-14 15:14:24.498: ERROR/FragmentManager(15743):   View Hierarchy:
10-14 15:14:24.498: ERROR/FragmentManager(15743):     com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView{41fd9b60 V.E..... R....... 0,0-480,854}
10-14 15:14:24.498: ERROR/FragmentManager(15743):       android.widget.LinearLayout{41fda158 V.E..... ........ 0,0-480,854}
10-14 15:14:24.498: ERROR/FragmentManager(15743):         android.view.ViewStub{41fdac50 G.E..... ......I. 0,0-0,0 #1020319}
10-14 15:14:24.498: ERROR/FragmentManager(15743):         android.widget.FrameLayout{41fdaeb0 V.E..... ........ 0,0-480,854 #1020002 android:id/content}
10-14 15:14:24.498: ERROR/FragmentManager(15743):           android.widget.LinearLayout{41fdb540 V.E..... ......I. 0,0-480,854}
10-14 15:14:24.498: ERROR/FragmentManager(15743):             android.widget.FrameLayout{41fdb958 V.E..... ........ 0,0-480,60 #7f0a0001 app:id/tabs_frame}
10-14 15:14:24.498: ERROR/FragmentManager(15743):               android.widget.LinearLayout{41fde340 V.E..... ........ 0,0-480,60 #7f0a000a app:id/ll_actionbar}
10-14 15:14:24.498: ERROR/FragmentManager(15743):                 
10-14 15:14:24.501: ERROR/FragmentManager(15743): android.widget.Button{41fde710 VFED..C. ........ 0,0-158,60 #7f0a000b app:id/actionbar_btn1}
10-14 15:14:24.501: ERROR/FragmentManager(15743):                 android.widget.Button{41fdefa8 VFED..C. ........ 161,0-319,57 #7f0a000c app:id/actionbar_btn2}
10-14 15:14:24.501: ERROR/FragmentManager(15743):                 android.widget.Button{41fdf7f8 VFED..C. ........ 322,0-480,57 #7f0a000d app:id/actionbar_btn3}
10-14 15:14:24.501: ERROR/FragmentManager(15743):             android.widget.LinearLayout{41fdbcd8 V.E..... ........ 0,60-0,803}
10-14 15:14:24.501: ERROR/FragmentManager(15743):             android.widget.LinearLayout{41fdc0e8 V.E..... ........ 0,803-480,854}
10-14 15:14:24.502: ERROR/FragmentManager(15743):               android.widget.Button{41fdc4f8 VFED..C. ........ 3,3-237,48 #7f0a0002 app:id/btnAdd_main}
10-14 15:14:24.502: ERROR/FragmentManager(15743):               android.widget.Button{41fdd618 VFED..C. ........ 243,3-477,48 #7f0a0003 app:id/btnDel_main}
10-14 15:14:24.502: ERROR/FragmentManager(15743):   Looper (main, tid 1) {41f604f8}
10-14 15:14:24.502: ERROR/FragmentManager(15743):     Message 0: { when=-47ms callback=android.widget.TextView$2 target=android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewRootHandler callback=android.widget.TextView$2@4203b978 target=Handler (android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewRootHandler) {42037678} }
10-14 15:14:24.502: ERROR/FragmentManager(15743):     Message 1: { when=-47ms callback=android.widget.TextView$2 target=android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewRootHandler callback=android.widget.TextView$2@4203d640 target=Handler (android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewRootHandler) {42037678} }
10-14 15:14:24.502: ERROR/FragmentManager(15743):     Message 2: { when=-47ms callback=android.widget.TextView$2 target=android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewRootHandler callback=android.widget.TextView$2@4203e978 target=Handler (android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewRootHandler) {42037678} }
10-14 15:14:24.502: ERROR/FragmentManager(15743):     Message 3: { when=-21ms what=6 arg2=1 target=android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewRootHandler target=Handler (android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewRootHandler) {41fe1f40} }
10-14 15:14:24.502: ERROR/FragmentManager(15743):     (Total messages: 4, idling=false, quitting=false)
10-14 15:14:24.507: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(15743): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-14 15:14:24.507: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(15743): Process: com.example.dictionarydemo_2, PID: 15743
10-14 15:14:24.507: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(15743): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No view found for id 0x7f0a001b (com.example.dictionarydemo_2:id/frameLayout1_wordsAdd) for fragment WordsAddForm1_Fragment{42044978 #2 id=0x7f0a001b}
10-14 15:14:24.507: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(15743):     at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:882)
10-14 15:14:24.507: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(15743):     at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1062)
10-14 15:14:24.507: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(15743):     at android.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:698)
10-14 15:14:24.507: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(15743):     at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1447)
10-14 15:14:24.507: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(15743):     at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:443)
10-14 15:14:24.507: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(15743):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:808)
10-14 15:14:24.507: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(15743):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:103)
10-14 15:14:24.507: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(15743):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
10-14 15:14:24.507: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(15743):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5292)
10-14 15:14:24.507: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(15743):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-14 15:14:24.507: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(15743):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
10-14 15:14:24.507: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(15743):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:824)
10-14 15:14:24.507: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(15743):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:640)
10-14 15:14:24.507: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(15743):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
10-14 15:14:25.034: ERROR/(675): Could not open '/data/data/hotplug/cmd'
10-14 15:14:25.034: ERROR/(675): error : 2, No such file or directory
```

P.S. Чтобы долго не копать код, скажу сразу: в зависимости от выбранного элемента в `Spinner`, я пытаюсь вставить фрагмент с определенным количеством `EditText`. Для позиции 0 — 2 `EditText`, для позиции 1 — 4 `EditText`.

- Вынес метод в `onAttach`. Не помогло. Вот код:

  @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
      super.onAttach(activity);
      Log.i("APP", "1");

  ```
  spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
      public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View itemSelected, int selectedItemPosition, long selectedId) {
          FragmentTransaction fTransaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
          switch (selectedItemPosition) {
          case 0:
              Log.i("APP", "2");
              fTransaction.add(R.id.frameLayout1_wordsAdd, new WordsAddForm1_Fragment());
              break;
          case 1:
              Log.i("APP", "3");
              fTransaction.add(R.id.frameLayout1_wordsAdd, new WordsAddForm2_Fragment());
              break;
          }
          Log.i("APP", "4");
          fTransaction.commit();
          Log.i("APP", "5");
      }

      public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
      }
  });
  Log.i("APP", "6");
  ```

  }

В лог выходит только 1.

Comment: Чтобы долго не копать код надо прикладывать stacktrace ошибки и соответствующий фрагмент кода где она возникает, а не весь код проекта.

Comment: @temq, у меня 13 классов и 8 файлов разметки. Я достал самое нужное.

Comment: @bukashka101, a ошибка-то какая?.. И на какой строке?

Comment: @bukashka101 самое нужное это stacktrace ошибки и кусок кода где она возникает. И кстати 7 у вас выводится в лог при создании фрагмента, а не при выборе элемента в спинере.

Comment: @temq, 6 тоже выводится в лог, при создании фрагмента. ``Spinner``, при создании "нажимается" на 0.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб,  fTransaction.commit();
    Log.i("APP", "6");
   }

   public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
   }
  });

  Log.i("APP", "7");
  return v;

6 выводится, а 7 нет. Я даже не знаю, где тут может быть ошибка...

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, я добавил лог.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, я попробовал написать:

WordsAddForm1_Fragment wordsAdd_1 = new WordsAddForm1_Fragment();       fTransaction.add(R.id.frameLayout1_wordsAdd, wordsAdd_1);, но мне выдало ошибку "Cannot refer to the non-final local variable wordsAdd_1 defined in an enclosing scope"

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, перепишу все под ``Activity``...

Comment: Скорее всего вы просто вызываете FragmentManager до добавление фрагмента в активити. Попробуйте перенести ваш код назначения слушателя спиннеру в `onAttach`

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, блин! Я уже фрагмент удалил :). Пойду восстанавливать.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, вынес. Не помогло. Я снизу вопроса закинул код.

Comment: Попробуйте использовать getChildFragmentManager вместо  getFragmentManager http://stackoverflow.com/a/25214252/3212712

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, тогда требует минимальный API 17, a у меня 14.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, на время перенесусь на ``Activity``, пока не найду ответ. Там с ``Activity`` немного другие тараканы.

Comment: @bukashka101, а вы уверены, что вам обязательно нужно фрагмент в фрагмент добавлять? Разве никак нельзя без него обойтись?..

Comment: @ЮрийСПб,  можно обойтись, если вызвать ``Activity`` без ``ActionBar`` или такой же диалог (как он работает не имеет значения, главное чтобы выглядел так же и я мог добавлять в него фрагменты, а с них "собирать" текст из ``EditText``).

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, а что будет, если перехватить вьюшку, которую возвращает диалоговый фрагмент и в ней уже пытаться что-либо настраивать (с том числе и слушателей)?